# Proof and physical meaning of $I(X;Y) \leq \min \{ \log| \mathcal X |, \log| \mathcal Y | \}$

Tags: information-theory

The inequality holds,
$$I(X;Y) \leq \min \{ \log| \mathcal X |, \log| \mathcal Y | \}$$
where $I(X;Y)$ is the mutual information. I know that
$H(X) \leq \log| \mathcal X| $ is an upper bound on entropy, which can be prooved by $\log | \mathcal X|-H(X) \geq 0 $. 
And $I(X;Y) = H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$ by definition. 
Now my question is, how do I prove the above inequality? Besides, is there any physical meaning to it?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with: $I(X;Y) = H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$ as you did, i used the identity $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(X|Y)=H(Y)+H(Y|X)$ and got $I(X;Y) = H(Y)-H(X|Y)=H(X)-H(Y|X)$.

I can now enlarge both expressions by using your inequalities and the fact that $H(Z)\ge 0$ and get: 
$ I(X;Y) \le log(|\mathcal Y|) $ **and** $ I(X;Y) \le log(|\mathcal X|) $.

In order to get an "always true" inequality, I will have to pick the smallest of the two, and get $ I(X;Y) \le min{log(|\mathcal X|),log(|\mathcal Y|)} $

Comment: I see. I think I missed the part where $ H(X|Y) = H(Y) - H(X, Y) $.
But I still couldn't get the physical meaning..

Comment: If i try to think intuitively about information measures I usually use venn diagrams (though I currently have [doubts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859121/representing-pairwise-independent-but-not-independent-occurrences-with-venn-diag) whether this is always good). anyway, mutual information is the intersect of the two areas that represent $X$ and $Y$ entropy. thus if $X$'s area is smaller than $Y$'s area, $I(X,Y)$ is limited by $X$'s area. if you also use the fact that $H(X) \le log(|\mathcal X|)$ than you can understand where this inequality comes from..