# Representing pairwise-independent but not independent occurrences with venn diagram

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, independence

For $A,B$ and $ C $ partially pairwise independent occurrences (i.e. $I(A;B)=0$, $I(A;C)=0$ ), it is not true to say that $I(A;B,C)=0$, since $I(A;B,C)=I(A;B)+I(A;B|C)$ [**<-this is not correct, see edit**] and we have no information about $I(A;B|C)$.

If i had to use venn diagram on the above case, i would use this diagram, in which $I(A;B,C)=0$.

[image: my venn interpertation]

I use venn diagram often when I need to prove/disprove equalities and inequalities in information measures, but my intuition seems to mislead me here.. So my question is - is it possible to draw an appropriate diagram for this case? or should i stop using such diagrams since they do not fit all cases?

**EDIT**: i have made a mistake when i wrote down my question here, possibly misleading some of the answers. the correct identity is $I(A;B,C)=I(A;B)+I(A;C|B)$ (note its A;C|B and not A;B|C). when wrote in the correct way, it is possible to use the inequality ("conditional reduces entropy") and get $I(A;B,C)=I(A;B)+I(A;C|B)\le I(A;B)+I(A;C)=0$ (the last equality comes form the question terms). this only confuses me more, since i did not expect $I(A;B,C)$ to be zero (again, pairwise independent between A,B and A,C).

**EDIT2**: Im not sure about this inequality $I(A;B)+I(A;C|B)\le I(A;B)+I(A;C)$. if anyone can help out, ill be glad. I will update when i will be sure what happens here.

Comment: Is $I(A;B)$ the probability of $A$ and $B$ both occuring? What does $B|C$ mean?

Comment: Please explain your notation.

Comment: $I(A;B)$ is the mutual information between A and B. $I(A;B|C)$ is the mutual information of A and B given C.

Answer (score 1):

In this [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/42490), we have obtained a case:
[image: Improved case diagram]

Here, $B$ and $C$ are independent random variables which can each take a value of $0$ or $1$ with equal probability. It is clear that $B$ and $C$ each have 1 bit of entropy. Let the bits be represented by fair coins.

Here, $A$ is defined as $B\ \text{XOR}\ C$. It is clear that $A$ is determined by both coins, so in the diagram $A$ must include both $B$ and $C$.

But, it has been shown that $A$ only has $1$ bit of entropy. Therefore, the grey space (that is, the space in $A$ but outside $B$ and $C$) contains $-1$ bits of entropy, which makes the Venn diagram invalid.

Therefore, there exists a case for which no Venn diagram is appropriate.

This is a counter-example to the following statement:

> For any three random variables $A,B,C$ such that I$(A;B)=0$ and $I(A;C)=0$, a Venn diagram that represents $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be drawn according to entropy.

Comment: as i said, it is possible that $I(A;B,C) \ne 0$ since i only have pair-wise independency, and this cannot be seen from the diagram, so how can this be correct?

Comment: Please confirm, A is independent from both B and C, right? Then it's impossible for anything in A to be in either or both of B and C.

Comment: As far as venn diagrams go - i think you are correct. But the tricky part is the pairwise independency. check out [wiki-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence) for more info.

Comment: @sagivd If you really meant $A,B$ and $A,C$ are pairwise independent as defined in the wiki article, then the notations $I(A;B)=0$ and $I(A;C)=0$ are incorrect.

Comment: If the notation is correct _and_ they are pairwise independent, then either A or either of B and C is 0.

Comment: @sagivd I think the problem is in your _notation_.

Comment: I am sure that if A and B are independent then $I(A;B)=0$. I am not sure about the converse, but i had the feeling that it is true as well. why do you think this is not true? I use the [first definition of mutual information from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), and you can see that it is zero only if X,Y are independent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42490/discussion-between-user351579-and-sagivd).

Comment: @sagivd I have edited my answer to answer your updated question.

Comment: See my answer. I believe venn diagrams cannot be used in such cases where conditional mutual information is involved. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: @sagivd There is _unconditional_ mutual information and _conditional_ mutual information. The existence of a third random variable does not affect the unconditional ones, such as $I(A;B)$ and $I(A;C)$. The sentence in the Wikipedia article means that if you add a condition to previously unconditional mutual information (for example turning $I(A;C)$ into $I(A;C|B)$) its value can change. But the value of $I(A;C)$ _itself_ does not change. With all due respect, I think you are the one who misunderstood.

Comment: @sagivd It's like adding an argument to a $max$ function expression, for example turning $max(x,y)$ to $max(x,y,z)$. The value of $max(x,y)$ itself does not change.

Comment: If it couldn't be represented by a Venn diagram, the Wikipedia article wouldn't include a Venn diagram.

Comment: I cannot agree. Since the element $I(A;B|C)$ can be smaller than $I(A;B)$, the element in the "middle" (which is denoted by $I(A;B;C)$, or **(2)** in your diagram, and is different than $I(A;B,C)$) can be negative. How can you use a Venn diagram for a negative value?

Comment: @sagivd Please state in terms of $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: @sagivd And no, it's not negative, because $I(X;Y)=I(X;Y|Z)+I(X;Y;Z)$, or equivalently, $I(X;Y)-I(X;Y|Z)=I(X;Y;Z)$. If $I(X;Y|Z)$ is smaller than $I(X;Y)$, $I(X;Y;Z)$ would be _positive_.

Comment: !!!!$I(X;Y|Z)$ is the part of $I(X;Y)$ which is **outside** $Z$ ($Z$ is given, so no entropy from $Z$). $I(X;Y;Z)$ is is the part of $I(X;Y)$ which is **inside** $Z$.

Comment: Check again: My point was that $I(A;B|C)$ (or $I(X;Y|Z)$) can be smaller, greater or equal to $I(A;B)$, which means that $I(A;B;C)$ can be negative.

Comment: If the value of a random variable is given, it ceases to have entropy.

Comment: I understand the notation using the Venn diagram. I am saying the the diagram is INVALID in this situation because it cannot depict negative sizes.

Comment: How can it be greater than $
I(A;B)$?

Comment: Let's move this to chat again. The comment count is sharply increasing.

Comment: Honestly: I don't know. the course i took did not include this information. I am basing this on the link i gave from wikipedia.

Comment: @sagivd I have edited the answer again.

Comment: @sagivd I'm testing the concept, with paper and pen.

Comment: @sagivd It turns out assigning numbers to "number-of-determining-bits-based" doesn't work in some cases. So just use the upper part.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information):

> Conditioning on a third random variable may either increase or decrease the mutual information

I believe this fact **prevents the use of venn diagram** in such cases where it is relevant, since (as the previous answer and also myself stated) in the diagram it is clear that $I(A;B) \ge I(A;B|C)$, but this is actually **NOT** true.

EDIT: I am accepting my own answer since I was not convinced that @user351579 is 100% correct, and honestly - knowing that Venn diagram does not work in ALL cases is an answer i am satisfied with. For a deeper discussion of ways around this, see my conversation\chat with @user351579 and\or his answer.

Comment: There are still cases where Venn diagrams is usable, such as when entropy equals the number of determining bits. But I presume a counter-example is enough.

Comment: Actually, $I(A;B) \geq I(A;B|C)$ is true only when $A, B, C$ forms a Markov chain ( $A \to B \to C$ ), which means $A$ and $C$ are conditionally independent given $B$.

Comment: @Julie I understand that $I(A;B) \ge (A;B|C)$ is true when $A,B,C$ forms a markov chain, but why is it **only** true with this condition?

Comment: Sorry I should correct it as: If $X \to Y \to Z$ then $ I(A;B) \geq I(A;B|C)$ AND without the condition $X \to Y \to Z$, both $ I(A;B) \geq I(A;B|C)$ and $ I(A;B) < I(A;B|C) $ could happen

Comment: this looks correct to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in information theory, but here's my opinion after reading your discussion and links. 
I think the point is that in a three-set Venn diagram, the overlapping part of $A$ and $B$ isn't $I(A;B)$ but $I(A;B|C)$ which may not equal to $I(A;B)$. 
And $ I(A;B) = 0 $ doesn't imply $ I(A;B|C) = 0 $ since the inequality
$ I(A;B|C) \leq I(A;B) $ is under the condition of $ X \to Y \to Z $ 
Thus, returning to your question, it might be impossible to draw an appropriate diagram for this case unless you have the information about $I(A;B|C)$, in my opinion.

Comment: $I(A;B|C)$ is the intersecting part of $A$ and $B$ **which is not in $C$**. $I(A;B)$ is always the entire intersecting part of $A$ and $B$. For more information read this section of the Wikipedia article about mutual information : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Relation_to_other_quantities

Comment: @Julie I edited the question. i am now confused about the whole situation..